# Codename One - googlemaps cn1lib Javadocs and code completion with NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, codenameone, javadoc, code-completion

I'm using NetBeans and I imported the Google Map's native cn1lib in my Codename One project, according to this guide (Configuration section):

https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-improved-native-google-maps.html.

I can't find API documentation of MapContainer class; moreover, code completion for that class does not work in NetBeans.

How can I do?

---

**EDIT**

After restarting NetBeans, the code completion works.

However, the API documentation does not work. In fact, inside code completion pop-up, I can read the following message:

> Javadoc not found. Either Javadoc documentation for this item does not exist or there is no attached Javadoc to the JAR file containing this item.

What's wrong? Does Javadoc documentation exist for the MapContainer class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw that myself and chalked it off to NetBeans flakiness. Turns out that it isn't...

The GoogleMaps cn1lib we have in the extension manager is missing the stubs file that should exist as a part of the cn1lib and provides that JavaDoc completion.

This is my locally built cn1lib in NetBeans:

[image]

This is the one I downloaded from the extension manager:

[image]

You will notice the missing `stubs.zip` in the latter which is due to a bad build script from one of our engineers. We'll try to fix this and update the lib. Once we do that you should be able to download an update from the extension manager and refresh libs again to get the new version.

Comment: Ok Shai, thank you. Actually stubs.zip also misses to my project. I'm waiting for the fix.

Comment: It should be up now

Comment: Hello Shai, I updated the library: now I can see stubs.zip. Unfortunately I can't see the Javadoc completion. Moreover, launching the "Refresh cn1lib files" command, I get the error: _Target "refresh-libs" does not exist in the project_

Comment: I closed NetBeans and I manually deleted build.xml and build-impl.xml files. After that, I again open NetBeans and finally I could see the Javadoc completions. However the "Refresh cn1lib files" command returns the same error.

Comment: You don't need to close netbeans but you do need to open extension manager and download the updated cn1lib before doing the refresh. Refresh only updates the local cn1libs it doesn't fetch new versions

Comment: So, that error in refreshing is normal when there is nothing to update locally, correct?

Comment: No. I didn't notice you deleted the XML files... Why would you do that??? I suggest you restore them.